# How to take multiple user input from a single slider and update in the database based on a single button in Streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-input, streamlit

I am building an app in streamlit where I have a input dataframe in which I have a discount column for all the products listed like pant, shirt, jeans etc. I want to give the flexibility to user to update the discount value for any item.

So firstly I have a selectbox (Dropdown) in which user will select an item and then there is a slider from which user can modify the discount value for that item between 0 to 100%.
After selecting the dropdown item and changing discount value on slider, user will click on the update button after which that discount value will go in the original dataframe and will get updated.
But now the problem is, if user is going to do this task for next item and follow the same process, after clicking the update button, discount will get modified for the 2nd item but will revert back to the original discount for the first item.

I am not able to think of any logic here.

I tried:

```
Key_Input = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select item',df['item'].unique().tolist())
    if Key_Input:
        Discount = st.sidebar.slider('Discount', 0.0,1.0, 0.01)
    if st.sidebar.button('Update Discount Value'):
        df_new['DISC'] = np.where((df_new['item'] == Key_Input, Discount,df_new['DISC'])
        
    st.write(df_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `st.experimental_data_editor`; [more info in docs](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.experimental_data_editor).